# JavaFX Observable where the value can be swapped

Tags: javafx

I am writing a small experimental desktop application. Basically it has the options to display a list of recipes and detailed information about a single recipe.

To accomplish that i implemented a class called `RecipeContext` that stores a `ObservableList<Recipe>` that i bind to a `TableView`, so the view gets automatically updated if i add to, or remove from the collection.

I want something similar for the single recipe, an Observable where i simply have to change the contained recipe and have the view automatically update to display the new recipe information.

To make this a bit more clear, i want something like this:

```
SingleObservable<Recipe> detailedRecipe = new SingleObservable<>(new Recipe("A"));
detailedInformationController.bindRecipeObservable(detailedRecipe);
// Recipe A is displayed
detailedRecipe.set(new Recipe("B"));
// View is notified about the change and displays Recipe B
```

Is there a class that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleObjectProperty` will do what you want.

```
SimpleObjectProperty<Recipe> detailedRecipe = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new Recipe("A"));
...
detailedRecipe.set(new Recipe("B"));
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleObjectProperty.html

Comment: Awesome, just what i needed.